# C basics, convert integers 0 and 1 to char*

Tags: c

Please recommendation for most simple conversion from integer where integers can be only 0 and 1 to char*, in C language.

I have function which returns 0 or 1 as integer.

```
gtk_toggle_button_get_active(GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON(mytogglebutton));
```

In other module it is function and in third declaration.

```
int set_locals(char* s_setting, char* s_value);
```

I try with:

```
set_locals("my_prop", (char*)gtk_toggle_button_get_active(GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON(mytogglebutton)));
```

But this won't work.

I know how to use sprintf, but when here is only 0 and 1 maybe someone know shorter way?

Comment: You want the pointer to either be null or 1? Are you sure you don't mean you want the character it points to to be 0 or 1?

Comment: Well, as you can see I still have trouble with pointers, but above I illustrated situation well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The shortest way for this would be using the ternary conditional operator:

```
set_locals("my_prop", 
     gtk_toggle_button_get_active(GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON(mytogglebutton)) ? "1" : "0" );
```

However this is a `const char*`, but as you presented the problem, I don't think it will be an issue.

Comment: This is a brilliant answer :)

Comment: I was just going to write same answer... damn I hate it when I'm too slow ;)

Comment: Thank you Luchian. Short and fully functional. Just what I'm searching for. In some other languages this condition is called 'IIF'.

Comment: `"1"` and `"0"` are **NOT** of type `const char*`. Read the standard. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf

Answer (score 2):

char* represents a pointer to a memory location containing a char (or the beginning of a contiguous array of char). As such, you cannot use the values 0 or 1 directly without causing the program to fail, since 0 and 1 do ***not*** represent a memory location.

What you can do is use the ternary operator as follows:

```
gtk_toggle_button_get_active(GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON(mytogglebutton)) ? "1" : "0"
```

and provide it as an argument to set_locals.

Comment: I was guessing he wants "0" and "1".

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Yes, me too, but submitted my answer too soon. Yours in more complete though.

Answer (score 1):

```
char x[] = "0";
if (gtk_toggle_button_get_active(GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON(mytogglebutton))) *x = '1';
set_locals("my_prop", x);
```

Comment: Not shortest, but in certain conditions absolutely applicable. Thanx.